# Can I use page-wide scroll with my core-list

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, core-elements

On my page I have core-list which is almost in the middle of page and is about 50% of page's height and width. I don't want to have scroller in the middle of my page. Instead I'd like core-list to scroll as page is scrolled.
Is it possible? Can I use "scrollTarget"? Setting scrollTarget to html element doesn't work (as it doesn't implment getScrollTop/setScrollTop).

Comment: look at "core-scroll-header' and "core-header" here : https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome-material/blob/master/index.html   maybe that helps for screen wide scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with assigning scrollTarget to my root div that works surprisingly perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add css to html "overflow-y:auto"  and set scrollTarget to it or use header-panel and set scroll target of list to it